# How to view .xml output on the go? (Android App-building help)

Tags: android, xml, ide, android-emulator

I'm a newbie Android App Developer, also new with xml. I was just wondering if there is an easier way to view xml output other than using eclipse to compile the android application (java + xml) and then see output in the android emulator. Just asking because it takes forever to check my UI through eclipse IDE to turn on android emulator then open my application, and I feel that there must be an easier way. I have searched for solutions but either I'm wording it incorrectly or I just do not know the correct terminology or there is no other way(hopefully not this option). Please help me figure out to how to run XML code to check and see the proper UI output (its layout, widgets in correct places etc.) without having to compile my application code every time.

I have already looked into DroidDraw - it provides one output within the the application and another output in android emulator. I find it quite inconsistent.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You may already be doing this but you only need to open the emulator once - once it's running you can just deploy the application again from Eclipse, which only takes a few seconds.

Comment: OMG, THANK YOU SO MUCH. I WAS restarting the emulator every time. Now I simply run it once and whenever I update my code, I restart the APPLICATION only! Thank you again! Hehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very great, but Eclipse with the android plugin has a visual mode where you can see a preview of your xml immediately. It won't give you 100% accuracy but it does definitely help with simple mistakes. Just open your layout xml in eclipse, and notice the two tabs at the bottom: one is for the xml text, the other for the visual representation of it. You have dropdown menus at the top to try your layout on different screen sizes and orientations.

Comment: Thank you so much your reply! This tool is awesome and it really helps! I never did any mobile applications before lol. Now I love coding for Android.